# Flex Actionscript (AS3) get available printers

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, printing, actionscript

How to get list of available printers connected to the computer, using `AS3`??

It seems that FlexPrintJob class and other provided classes doesn't provide me the solutions, since they focus more on printer specifications (print width , height etc) .

There's a flash.PrintJob class that provides a list of printers, but this is not applicable to my project since this is for flash and air.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code will work for you

var availablePrinters:Vector. = PrintJob.printers;
    var printersCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    if (availablePrinters) 
        for (var i:int = 0; i < availablePrinters.length; i++) 
              printersCollection.addItem(availablePrinters[i]);

If (availablePrinters) is available when running with the CTR + enter, however, when the nested SWF is embedded in the HTML, the availablePrinters is null does not know for any reason

Comment: PrintJob.printers is air only it seems. src: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html#printers